# Wordpress multisite URL redirection

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I have a few different sites in a multisite setup, and would like to have different URLs for each.

The site is currently hosted at

```
http://54.241.13.224/
```

(Ubuntu 12.04 running Apache2) and I would like the domain

```
http://www.formidableapps.co.uk
```

to point to the multisite

```
http://54.241.13.224/formidableapps/
```

I have tried searching for some help and done a little playing with the .htaccess and virtualhosts files, but haven't had any luck so far.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using this plugin?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

it describes the thing you need...

Comment: Thanks. A nice, easy fix :)